# Composer Error in Jenkins

Tags: php, docker, jenkins, composer-php

I have been trying to setup a build system for PHP and has the following Jenkins pipeline.

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'my-custom-image' } }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'composer config --global --auth http-basic.repo.packagist.com token mytokencode'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here it is pulling the docker image, but when the composer command is executed, it it throwing following error :

```
Cannot create cache directory /.composer/cache/repo/https---repo.packagist.com-domain/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache
Cannot create cache directory /.composer/cache/files/, or directory is not writable. Proceeding without cache


  [ErrorException]                                                                         
  touch(): Unable to create file /.composer/config.json because No such file or directory
```

and the build is failing. How can I fix this ?

Answer (score 0):

You could set the COMPOSER_HOME environment variable to the actual directory, them Composer will save all the cache data there. Something like:

```
pipeline {
    agent { docker { image 'my-custom-image' } }
    stages {
        stage('Build') {
            steps {
                sh 'COMPOSER_HOME=$(pwd) composer config --global --auth http-basic.repo.packagist.com token mytokencode'
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The message is gone, but this cache will never be used again, so, not solved at all

Answer (score 0):

I was able to use composer cache by **creating a volume** between my Jenkins machine and the Docker image. You can try to reproduce:

At your pipeline script, create the volume using an argument:

```
agent {
  docker {
    image 'my-custom-image'
    args '-v $HOME/.composer/cache:/usr/local/share/composer/cache'
  }
}
```

Check where your **$HOME** directory is pointing to, it can be different depending on how you installed Jenkins. I'm using it as an apt package on Ubuntu 16. For me, it's pointing to **/var/lib/jenkins**

Inside your $HOME directory, a folder named ".composer" is needed with right permissions so the docker can use it. I set it up with **chmod -R 775**.